# jTextField not updating value depending on jradiobutton selection

Tags: java, sql, jtextfield, jradiobutton

I have 2 jRadioButtons, jRadiobutton2 and jRadioButton3.
I added action performed on both to fill a jTextfield

If the jRadioButton2 is selected, a function get the last ProfessorID from the database, and sets the value + 1 to the textfield, for example if the last professor id = 1 the new value is 2.

If the jRadioButton3 is selected, a function get the last StudentID from the database, and sets the value + 1 to the textfield

It's the same textfield for both jRadioButtons

I have 2 functions LastStudentID() and LastProfessorID, each gets the last ID of the corresponding table.

The problem is that it only set the text when the jRadioButton2 is selected. If the jRadioButton3 is selected it doesn't, I tried to print the new value it's correct, but it's not setting it in the texfield.

My code the is following:

```
    public int LastStudentID() {
 String query = "SELECT IdStudent FROM student ORDER BY IdStudent DESC LIMIT 1";
 try {
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
   idstudent = (rs.getInt("IdStudent"));
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
 }
 return idstudent;
}

public int LastProfessorID() {
 String query = "SELECT IdProfessor FROM professor ORDER BY IdProfessor DESC LIMIT 1";
 try {
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
   idprofessor = (rs.getInt("IdProfessor"));
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
 }
 return idprofessor;
}

// ums is an instance of a class containing the functions
idstudent = ums.LastStudentID();
idprofessor = ums.LastProfessorID();

private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 // TODO add your handling code here:
 if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
  ID.setText(idprofessor + 1 + "");
 }
}

private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(jRadioButton3.isSelected()){
            ID.setText(idstudent+1+"");
ID.setText(idstudent+1+"");
        }
}
```

[image: This image shows the result of jRadionbutton2 selection (left part) and jRadioButton3 Selection (right Part). As you can see, the textfield is updated in when professor is selected, and not updated when the student is selected, although it's visible in the console the value 5]

Comment: can you show the other code which is related to this code?

Comment: Could we ask for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: My guess is it’s not related to the database. If this is correct, you can leave that code out.

Comment: show the code where you add the action listeners to  `jRadioButton2` and `jRadioButton3` (i bit you registed jRadioButton2  twice) damn copy/paste :) ?!

Comment: Seriously Yazan copy paste?
Nope. The code is shown above
Besides on copy paste you get an exlamation point on your JFrame.

Anyway I rewrote the code from scratch, and it worked

Comment: wow wow wow, come down man, i did not mean copy/paste (steal) from others, i meant inside your code itself (i personally do it) when i need to rewrite same code for different button for ex, i just copy the same lines, -sometimes- i forget to change the reference, so they both affect same View. sorry if u got me wrong . --- as we have this cleared, now what i mean is the code where you add the listener, not the function itself , like `jtext1.addAction...`

Comment: I meant copy pasting from my code, I did it 2 years ago, I learnt from it. 
No problem, it's just frustrating having it work at one point then crash at another